# ktor failing to parse response No transformation found: class io.ktor.utils.io.ByteBufferChannel

Tags: kotlin, httpclient, ktor

I am relatively new to Kotlin and Ktor. And while playing around, I was trying to parse response from the HTTP response, but it always throws an error at me.

```
package com.example

import com.example.models.SpaceShip
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.call.*
import io.ktor.client.engine.apache.*
import io.ktor.client.request.*
import io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.json.*
import io.ktor.server.plugins.contentnegotiation.*
import io.ktor.server.response.*
import io.ktor.server.routing.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit =
    io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)



@Suppress("unused") // application.conf references the main function. This annotation prevents the IDE from marking it as unused.
fun Application.module() {

    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json()
    }

    val client = HttpClient(Apache)

    routing {

        get("/spaceship") {
            val ship = SpaceShip("viktor", 2.2)
            call.respond(ship)
        }

        get("/consumeService") {
            val ship: SpaceShip =
                client.request("http://0.0.0.0:8080/spaceship"){
                    accept(ContentType.Application.Json)
                }.body()
            call.respond(ship)
        }
    }
}

@Serializable
data class SpaceShip(val name: String, val fuel: Double)
```

Here is the error while making a request to GET http://0.0.0.0:8080/consumeService

```
2022-04-17 10:59:09.432 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-3] ERROR Application
                - Unhandled: GET - /consumeService
io.ktor.client.call.NoTransformationFoundException: No transformation found: class io.ktor.utils.io.ByteBufferChannel -> class com.example.models.SpaceShip
with response from http://0.0.0.0:8080/spaceship:
status: 200 OK
response headers: 
Content-Length: 28
, Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
, Connection: keep-alive

    at io.ktor.client.call.HttpClientCall.body(HttpClientCall.kt:92)
    at com.example.ApplicationKt$module$2$2.invokeSuspend(Application.kt:54)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.resumeRootWith(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:138)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:112)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.access$loop(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:14)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun$continuation$1.resumeWith(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:62)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:46)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.resumeRootWith(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:138)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:112)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.access$loop(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:14)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun$continuation$1.resumeWith(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:62)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:46)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.resumeRootWith(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:138)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:112)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.access$loop(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:14)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun$continuation$1.resumeWith(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:62)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:46)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.resumeRootWith(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:138)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:112)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.access$loop(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:14)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun$continuation$1.resumeWith(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:62)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:46)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:469)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:503)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.EventLoopGroupProxy$Companion.create$lambda-1$lambda-0(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:263)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

While request to GET http://0.0.0.0:8080/spaceship
is successfull

```
Content-Length: 28
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive

{
  "name": "viktor",
  "fuel": 2.2
}
```

Comment: You've enabled serialization on your server, but you also need to enable it for your client, check out [documentation](https://ktor.io/docs/serialization-client.html)

Comment: @PhilDukhov can you please expand on this? Is there some code that needs to be implemented on the client or is this code on the server that references the client?

Comment: @mars8 ktor for the client and for the server are two different frameworks made in the same style, they do not need each other to work (of course you can use the client on the server side to do some queries, and made your app a server). so you need to enable serialization on both sides - . You have a problem with the side that fails =) Both server and client have "Content negotiation and serialization" documentation section

Comment: @PhilDukhov thanks for response. I realised my issue was specifying the wrong Type object on response which was giving me the same error as OP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

thanks Pylyp Dukhov and Aleksei Tirman for helping solve this out.
So yeah I din't know that i need to enable it twice

```
package com.example

import com.example.models.SpaceShip
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.call.*
import io.ktor.client.engine.apache.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.contentnegotiation.ContentNegotiation as ClientContentNegotiation
import io.ktor.client.request.*
import io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.json.*
import io.ktor.server.plugins.contentnegotiation.ContentNegotiation as ServerContentNegotiation
import io.ktor.server.response.*
import io.ktor.server.routing.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json

fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit =
    io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)



@Suppress("unused") // application.conf references the main function. This annotation prevents the IDE from marking it as unused.
fun Application.module() {

    install(ServerContentNegotiation) {
        json()
    }

    val client = HttpClient(Apache){
        install(ClientContentNegotiation){
            json(Json {
                prettyPrint = true
                isLenient = true
            })
        }
    }

    routing {

        get("/spaceship") {
            val ship = SpaceShip("viktor", 2.2)
            call.respond(ship)
        }

        get("/consumeService") {
            val ship: SpaceShip =
                client.request("http://0.0.0.0:8080/spaceship"){
                    accept(ContentType.Application.Json)
                }.body()
            call.respond(ship)
        }
    }
}
```